# Rxjs use min operator on array property

Tags: angular, operators, min, rxjs5, ngrx

I understand we can use the min operator on an array of numbers. But how would i use it on an array of objects, with a number property?

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]).min();
```

This is how the docs describe it. This will emit `1`. How do i do this...

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromArray([{a: 1, b:"first"},{a: 3, b:"second"},{a: 5, b:"third"}]).min();
```

I want to use `min` by the inner property values. So, compare the values of `a` in each object in the array and emit that object.

I understand min takes a compare function, but i don't know if it can be used here.

I also want it to emit the object, not the minimum property value.

Edit:

So, i'm using Ngrx in an Angular 4 app and trying to use the `min` operator on a `store.select` Observable. For some reasong, the below code, where i first subscribe and then create another observable from the response and then use the min works, but if i skip the subscribe and try to use the min operator like the lower code, it fails and emits the complete array of ClientFacilities.

Anybody know what's going on? Aren't they both the same thing?

This works:

```
this.store.select(fromRoot.getClientFacilitiesArray).take(1).subscribe(res => {
                    Observable.from(res).min<ClientFacility>((a, b) => a.leaders_assigned - b.leaders_assigned)
                        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
                })
```

This fails:

```
this.store.select(fromRoot.getClientFacilitiesArray).take(1)
.min<ClientFacility>((a, b) => a.leaders_assigned - b.leaders_assigned)
                        .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Comment: *I understand min takes a compare function, but i don't know if it can be used here*: why couldn't it be used? Why don't you even try? The documentation  even has an example doing **exactly** what you want to achieve: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-min

Comment: I have. Compare takes two values. What would they be? Can't figure it out. Could you give an example?

Comment: As I just said, the documentation has an example. The function takes two objects emitted by your observable, and compares them. Just like Array.sort().

Comment: @JBNizet Wow.. i've been busting my head for an hour looking at another page in the docs. http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/min.html

Comment: I must admit that the Rxjs documentation sucks. And even the example I linked to is not really correct: the function should return 0 if both persons have the same age.

Comment: @JBNizet Could you take a look at the edit in the question. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Rx.Observable.fromArray([1,3,5,7,9,2,4,6,8]).min()` is an example for RxJS 4 that won't work with RxJS 5.

The proper place for RxJS 5 documentation is http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ , while http://reactivex.io/documentation/ contains RxJS 4 documentation.

According to [`min` operator documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-min), it can accept compare function, which behaves similarly the one accepted by [array `sort` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/6xJTQkTxTY2sR4En8RV4?p=preview) is an example:

```
Rx.Observable.from([{a: 1, b:"first"},{a: 3, b:"second"},{a: 5, b:"third"}])
.min((objA, objB) => objA.a - objB.a)
.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, they are different things. `min` processes an observable with multiple values and picks min value. In the second case it is an observable with a single value, which is an array. It likely should be `this.store.select(fromRoot.getClientFacilitiesArray).take(1).mergeMap(arr => Observable.from(arr)).min(...))`.